# Detemine Auth provider in fetchProvidersForEmail() in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to determine which auth provider/providers are user currently logged into with a particular email . It will be very great if someone provides me with the complete method for fb,google,twitter,github and email method .

I cant find anywhere on internet or Firebase docs the proper code to determine it .This is my code if its of any help guyz.

```
 mAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail(email[0]).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ProviderQueryResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ProviderQueryResult> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {

           //What to do ??                                                    }
     }
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside onComplete(), you can call task.getResult() to get back [ProviderQueryResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/ProviderQueryResult), which contains the list of Auth providers used by that user.

Comment: Note that `task.getResult()` returns `List<String>` and not `String[]`

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in you can use the following code to get the provider:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String providerId = firebaseUser.getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId();
```

Comment: User isn't logged in,  i need to check of user already exists in the Firebase db and if it does than from which provider.